# How do I change the action of a JButton after it's been clicked?

Tags: java, swing

I want to change the behavior of a JButton after it's been clicked.

```
JButton btn = new JButton();

btn.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        super.mouseClicked(e);
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(someLabel, "how are you?", "asd", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
});
```

I'd like to add something in the method mouseClicked in order to get another result when I click the same button one time more.

Comment: You should explain more precisely what sort of "actions" you want there. There are many different possible solutions. I just played around with an `Action` that just walks through a list of delegate `Action` objects, but who knows whether this is appropriate for you. Also, why are you doing all this in a mouse listener, and not in some `ActionListener`?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a boolean flag for that e.g.

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    super.mouseClicked(e);
    if (clicked) {} else {}
    // flip it
    clicked = !clicked;
}
```

Comment: That's very clever, thanks! 

But I didn't ask the right question, my bad.

After a second click, a third click should do something else entirely. Same thing with a fourth click and a fifth click and so on with other results.

Comment: @CarmeloSarta Then use an incrementing index with a `switch-case` structure.

Comment: thank you but that won't work. I need something more dynamic, the user could need to press the button a lot.

Comment: Could you be more specific with what you want your button to do? Maybe have a variable storing the total number of button clicks. Then you can do something with it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could implement a counter for the button. Every click the counter will increased. Then you could try it with a switch. Like this:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
 clickval++;
 switch(clickval){
  case 1:
   do this
   break;
  case 2:
  do that.
  break;
}
}
```